# counter need persist to remember the last number

Tags: javascript, counter, persist

I found this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/sac63azn/3/

https://fiddle.jshell.net/DinoMyte/sac63azn/3/show/

```
var num = 10000000;

setInterval(function()
  {   
    num++;
    console.log(num);
    $('div').text(num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
  },6000);
```

and it works almost the way I want it to. It is a counter where every 6 seconds, it will add a 1 to the number. For example: the number starts at 10,000,000 and then every 6 seconds, it adds a 1 to the number. The problem is when a user refresh or reloads the page, the number reverts back to the original 10,000,000. If after refresh or reload, is it possible the number will be saved from the last time? Persist? For example: the number is now 10,000,008, 6 seconds later it is 10,000,009, then the user click away or refresh or reloads the page, it should remember where the last number was left off: 10,000,009 and start counting from there.

Comment: Write it to a cookie. When you reload, first look to see if the cookie exists and set `num` to that instead of 10000000

Comment: if its an important number that should not be messed with you should use a server side language, if not a session variable will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` for this.

Just use this code

```
var num = localStorage.getItem('evaluatedTimer') || 10000000;

setInterval(function()
  {   
    num++;
    console.log(num);
    var currentTimer = num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    localStorage.setItem('evaluatedTimer', currentTimer');
    $('div').text(currentTimer );
  },6000);
```

Comment: I'm sorry guys beforehand. I haven't done the code check, so while implementing you might have to run it one more time.

Comment: I tried your code. It didn't work. Did I do it right?
http://test06.bycustomdesign.com/03.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set the var num value to javascript cookie. You can use the below javascript code to create, read or delete cookie val

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

So, in your case you can persist num value like this

var num = 10000000;

```
setInterval(function()
  {   
    num++;
    createCookie('persist_num', num, 1);
    console.log(readCookie('persist_num'));
    $('div').text(num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
  },600);
```

Comment: I tried your code, it didn't work. Did I miss something?

http://test06.bycustomdesign.com/04.html

Comment: It should work  because i have tested this before. Might b you are missing something like var num = 100000000;